# Speech to text in web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Been few days research this topic for Speech-to-text into web form.
I found the most ease way to do is using Google Speech API. The Google speech only can be use while connect Internet and only 50 request per day.

Beside that, I found project oxford which quite limitation due 5000 transaction per month and in WPF format.
Another open source I found using cmushphinx, sadly this open source most of project implement in Android or the accuracy for translating quite low.

I did found most of speech to text successful implement Microsoft SAPI in VB.net. Perhaps, I need to do in window form? Any suggestion?

Comment: why tagged asp.net and c# and vb.net together?

Comment: I just wanted make sure this speech-to-text enable in C sharp or vb.net format

Comment: `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483347/Speech-recognition-speech-to-text-text-to-speech-a`    Download the demo project for speech to text and text to speech ..